# APDU for getting UID from MIFARE DESFire?

Tags: uniqueidentifier, mifare, apdu, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

I am new to APDUs. I read the datasheet for DESFire. According to it we have:

```
CLA  = 0x90     
INS  = DESFire CMD Code                                            
P1   = 0x00        
P2   = 0x00
LC   = Length of wrapped Data    
data = DESFire command parameter(s) 
LE   = 0x00
```

I want get the DESFire UID, but I can't create the command APDU for this. 
Can anybody lead me into the right direction? I created this APDU but I am not sure if it's correct:

```
byte[8] cmd_apdu_getUID_part1= {0x90 , 0x93 , 0x20 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00};
```

And I don't understand the concept of parameters like LC and I don't find INS for get UID. Is it `0x93 ox20` for part 1 of UID and `0x95 0x20` for part 2 of UID?

Answer (score 11):

The commands `9x 20` are part of the lower ISO 14443-3 protocol and used during anticollision and activation of a card. APDUs, on the other hand, are exchanged on a higher protocol layer and only *after* activation of the card. Hence, you can't use these command codes in APDUs.

How to get the UID from a DESFire (EV1) card depends on what type of ID you actually want to get:

- **Get the UID that was actually used during the anti-collision phase**: This depends on what reader (and possibly device platform) you use. For instance, PC/SC compliant contactless smartcard readers typically allow to read the anti-collision identifier of the currently selected card using the PC/SC specific APDU

  ```
  FF CA 00 00 xx
  ```

  (where `xx` is either `00` or the expected length of the UID, for DESFire typically `04` or `07`).
- (DESFire EV1 only) **Get the UID of the card if the card's random-UID feature is not activated**: You would need to use the [GetVersion command](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libfreefare/blob/5459806659d5f6aa0e7705b88c48775ea6c861a6/libfreefare/mifare_desfire.c#L951). You would need to use the CLA byte 0x90 to indicate a wrapped native command, set INS to the command code 0x60, Lc and DATA would not be present:

  ```
  90 60 00 00 00
  ```

  The answer would look something like

  ```
  <7 response data bytes> 91 AF
  ```

  where the status code `91 AF` indicates that more data can be obtained with the command code set to 0xAF. So you have to send another command:

  ```
  90 AF 00 00 00
  ```

  The answer would (again) look something like

  ```
  <7 response data bytes> 91 AF
  ```

  so you have to send another 0xAF command. Then you'll get an answer of the form:

  ```
  <14 response data bytes> 91 00
  ```

  where the last 7 bytes of the response data contain the UID. See [parseGetVersion()](https://github.com/EsupPortail/esup-nfc-tag-server/blob/d27858c653635093b670d1a5a68f742b51176207/src/main/java/nfcjlib/core/DESFireEV1.java#L2106) on how to parse the received data.
- (DESFire EV1 only) **Get the UID of the card if the card's random-UID feature is activated**: This is by far more complex. You would first need to authenticate to the card. Only then you can use the [GetCardUID command](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libfreefare/blob/5459806659d5f6aa0e7705b88c48775ea6c861a6/libfreefare/mifare_desfire.c#L1113) to retrieve the actual card UID. This command would look like

  ```
  90 51 00 00 00
  ```

  The answer would look something like

  ```
  <UID (encrypted)> 91 00
  ```

Comment: How can I find out that random-UID feature is not activated or activated? This feature what used for? And you must know I have not changed My DESFire cards and I work on the undone and native card without any changes. Another question : What means anti-collision phase? Can you explain more about it?

Comment: And you dont tell me what are LC and data? what is meaning the wrapped Data and   DESFire command parameter(s)?

Comment: I understand meaning of anti-collision : An intelligent anti-collision mechanism allows more than one MIFARE DESFire EV1 in the field to be handled simultaneously. The anti-collision algorithm selects each MIFARE DESFire EV1 individually and ensures that the execution of a transaction with a selected MIFARE DESFire EV1 is performed correctly without data corruption resulting from other MIFARE DESFire EV1s in the field.    ------------------------ now I want know how can I activate random UID feature ? Also I couldnt find GetCardUID command (I saw the DESFire datasheet). What is it?

Comment: @soheylaab Why you didn't check this comprehensive answer as correct answer?! I think you forget to check answers always!

Comment: Dear Micheal, may I ask you to make me informed that why we need to know UID? I mean, in what kind of situations, having UID is useful?

Comment: Abraham, I believe that UID is necessary for authentication, more precisely to perform key diversification (on the reader side) and thus be able to perform reader<->card authentication.